# Animate feature not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make two buttons that slide when clicked and push the other button out of the viewport. For example:

Before clicked - [ blue | grey ]

Click blue     - [   all blue    ]

Get it? I have the html and css set up perfectly (I think), but I just can't get this jQuery code to animate and change the positioning of the element that contains the two buttons. It's driving me nuts. What I have so far is:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <a id='wrapper_photo' href=""></a>
        <a id='wrapper_video' href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    #container{
        width:760px;
        height:25px;
        background:#000000;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width:1520px;
        height:25px;
        background-color:#0F0;
        position:relative;
        left:-380px;
    }

    #wrapper_photo{
        width:760px;
        height:25px;
        background-color:#666666;
        float:left;
    }

    #wrapper_video {
        width:760px;
        height:25px;
        background-color:#0000CC;
        float:left;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wrapper_photo').click(function() {
            $('#wrapper').animate({
                left:"-=380"},
            5000);
        });
     });
</script>
```

I stopped when I couldn't get the left side to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u9sgcqd1/)**

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrapper_photo, #wrapper_video').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width:"100%"},
            5000);
        $(this).siblings('a').animate({
            width:'0px'
        },5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Works great on the fiddle but when I upload everything to my site, nothing moves. Any ideas?

Comment: have you included jQuery library properly? have you wrapped the code in a document ready function?

Comment: I wrapped the code in a ready function for you, if the library is properly included in the HTML, it should work

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure. Would this code [<script type="text/javascript" src="galleryslide.js"></script>] be linking it correctly or I have I missed something completely? And yes, I have it wrapped in a document ready function.

Comment: no, you need to download the jQuery library from this link (http://jquery.com/download/) and then include it to your HTML

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this new value for left will be set, so you can use `position()` [function](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to get value of `left` of `#wrapper` container and then calculate new value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrapper_photo').click(function() {
        var leftVal = $('#wrapper').position().left - 380;
        $('#wrapper').animate({
            left:leftVal},
            5000);
    });
});
```